# I can't connect to a https site server by Caddy using curl

Tags: php, ssl, curl, caddy, caddyfile

I am trying to contact a https site served by [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com) .  I get an error when trying to get the content with CURL even with

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
```

There is a certain amount of worry about setting this to false anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turn out that by default Caddy will communication with a minimum of version 
of tls 1.1 whereas my host was using 1.0.  If you add this to your caddyfile it should work if this is your issue.

```
example.ie {
tls {
   protocols tls1.0 tls1.2  #min max
 }
log access.log
errors err.log      
proxy / http://myexample.com:3032

}
```